# Jquery CheckBox Selection/Deselection optimally given X checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, unobtrusive-javascript

I have suppose say 'X' check-boxes(any input elements) in a Form and "M" option selection indexes ("M" less than equal to "X"). then how do i select the "M" option indexes/values and deselect the rest of check-boxes optimally?

i.e.Suppose I have 10 Checkboxes and 5 Option Indices(eg: 1,2,4,5,8) then i have to select
checkboxes with given index .

I could come up with the following code:

```
   HTML:

     <div id="Options">     
        <input id="choice_1"  type="checkbox" name="choice_1" value="Option1"><label for="choice_1">Option1</label>
        <input id="choice_2"  type="checkbox" name="choice_2" value="Option2"><label for="choice_2">Option2</label>
        <input id="choice_3"  type="checkbox" name="choice_3" value="Option3"><label for="choice_3">Option3</label>    

    ..
    ..till choice_10

     </div>

    IN JS:

   //Have to select checkboxes with "Value" in choicesToSelect and give a selection   
  //effect to its label
    var choicesToSelect={"Option1","Option9","Option3","Option4","Option2"};
    selectHighlightCheckBoxes(choicesToSelect);


    function selectHighlightCheckBoxes(choices){
     $.each(
                                choices, function(intIndex, objValue) {

//select based on id or value or some criteria
                                    var option = $("#Options :input[value=" + objValue + "]") ;                       
                                    if ($(option).is("input[type='radio']") || $(option).is("input[type='checkbox']")) {
                                        $(option).attr('checked', true);
                                        $(option).next('label:first').css({ 'border': '1px solid #FF0000', 'background-color': '#BEF781', 'font-weight': 'bolder' });
                                    } else if ($(option).is("input[type='text']")) {
                                        $(option).css({ 'border': '1px solid #FF0000', 'background-color': '#BEF781', 'font-weight': 'bolder' });
                                    } else {

                                    }
                                }
                         );
   }
```

But i want to also add effect to the **rest** (not in choicesToSelect array) also. 
(may be red color to those not in choiceToSelect) 
Can this be done in the one traversal/loop?
Optimally? or Better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can trim your code down to this, a bit faster:

```
var choicesToSelect = ["Option1","Option9","Option3","Option4","Option2"];
selectHighlightCheckBoxes(choicesToSelect);


function selectHighlightCheckBoxes(choices){
  $("#Options :input, label").removeAttr('checked').css({'border':'none', 'background-color':'none', 'font-weight':'normal'});
  $.each(choices, function(intIndex, objValue) {
    var option = $("#Options :input[value=" + objValue + "]"), toStyle = null;
    if (option.is(":radio, :checkbox")) {
        toStyle = option.attr('checked', true).next('label');
    } else if ($(option).is(":text")) {
        toStyle = option;
    }
    toStyle.css({ 'border': '1px solid #FF0000', 'background-color': '#BEF781', 'font-weight': 'bolder' });
  });
}
```

On the first line of the function, it unchecks and removes whatever styling you're applying.  Add anything you want the "off" elements to have as well.

On the `toStyle` line at the end, I consolidated your CSS to be defined in one spot.  In that `.css()` call you can set what you want the "on" elements to be, and change or remove styling that the "off" elements have.  [Here's a page you can play with to see it working](http://jsfiddle.net/TN6tr/) :)

Comment: thx.. but how to add effects/css to the items that are not selected?
eg: choicesToSelect in 'green' and those items not present("Off" elements) in choicesToSelect  to 'red'?

Comment: @Amitd - Do this in the top css, it applies to **all** the elements, then the loop goes over the selected ones.  In the `toStyle.css()` portion reverse or remove any styling applied to everything that you don't want on the selected ones, make sense?

Comment: @Nick: added this line before calling "selectHighlightCheckBoxes" :
$("#Options :input, label").removeAttr('checked').css({'border':'none', 'background-color':'red', 'font-weight':'normal'});

correct?

Comment: @Amitd - that works too, or it can be the first line in the method like I have it, but either case works, just run it before the loop.

Comment: @Nick: but if i had to give show/hide animations? then it will hide the all the options and then again make them visible?

Comment: @Amitd - I would `.hide()` chained to the `.css()` up top, hiding everything, and then `.fadeIn()` chained to the `toStyle.css()` to give a nice effect :)

Comment: @Nick:Strange the code/link doesn't seem to work on IE8?? 
JS error for 'background-color' :'none' CSS ..